# Ошибка "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

Tags: c#, winforms

Ошибка: `Входная строка имела неверный формат.` Помогите начинающему=)

Вот отрывок кода

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox9.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text) / Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text)).ToString();
}

private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox6.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(textBox5.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Вводи строку в верном формате и все будет хорошо.

Comment: хаха.Непонял)))

Comment: Вы пробное число через точку или запятую указываете?

Comment: Для русской локализации используется запятая как разделитель дробной части, а не точка.

Comment: и то , и то ошибку выдает

Comment: Где то в коде работает нормально а где то ни в какую

Comment: Приведите пример строки которую вводите.

Comment: Выведите на экран строку, которую пытаетесь конвертировать в double и посмотрите, что в ней не так. Как мы можем просто так угадать, какую строку вы вводите?

Comment: Используйте `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox` для ввода чисел.